# Opera img over input issue

Tags: html, css, opera

Next html works fine in all major browsers, except opera 12:
input with clickable icon inside (on click calendar is showed)

```
<input type='text' width='100px'/>
<img alt='icon' width='20' height='20' style='margin-left: -25px;'/>
```

In opera 12 img is hidden while input has not focus (Why?!), when input is focused img is visible, but when I click on img, input loses focus, img disappears and click is ignored.

Is there any way to solve the problem without changing markup just by css?
(z-index does not help)

Comment: Opera is a browser used by only 1% of the population => LOL
Look at this : http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-ww-yearly-2010-2013

Comment: It isn't really difficult to support opera browser for my site. Just some little things got in my way. =)

Comment: Also, statcounter gives other numbers for opera in Russia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was
   { position: relative; }
in the img css